# Cause of closed connection

Tags: java, oracle, performance

We have one of the customer java websphere applications pointing to oracle database encountering connection close error while doing the plsql stored procedure execution.  Sometimes after a few minutes into the stored procedure call and a few times after ~2 hours into execution. In a normal scenario, this job succeeds, within <10 seconds . So during failure time, it may have been waiting for some resource or other bottleneck that resulted in long execution time. So want to understand if anybody encountered such an error and what is the cause and fix of this?

The database is oracle version 11.2.0.4.

Below is the application log.

```
com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.ObjectClosedException: DSRA9110E: Connection is closed.
           at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcWrapper.createClosedException(WSJdbcWrapper.java:122)
           at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.activate(WSJdbcConnection.java:2936)
           at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(WSJdbcConnection.java:3512)
```

We found below oracle doc matching the error but it seems if it would have been this bug then rerun also would have been failed. So our case might be different.

Protocol Violation and Connection is Closed exceptions When Using JDBC 12.1.0.2 with WebSphere (Doc ID 2359390.1)

Comment: Could it be that a firewall kicked in? If so, enable dead client detection.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed log? Can you check the database log? Do you know what is the connection idle timeout for this database? Do you have `validationQuery` set in you dataSource properties? Does this error ever occur soon after starting the application or only after some time?